# NSTimer stop but unable to go to next page

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, dispatch-async

I am using NSTimer to call a device to take photos every 24.5 second.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    _photoTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:24.5 target:self selector:@selector(takePhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];     
});});
```

And at the 11th times, I switch to the main queue and call NSTimer stops, but it won't push to the next page.

```
-(void)takePhotos{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   //taking photos....
  currenPageNumber +=1;

dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //showing photos
 });
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (currentCount == 11){
         [_photoTimer invalidate];
         _photoTimer = nil;
         UploadVC * uploadVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UploadVC"];
         [self.navigationController presentViewController:uploadVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }     
   });
   });
 }
```

Comment: when your `currentCount` is incremented ?

Comment: What is the error that you get?  by the way presentViewController does not need to be called from self.navigationController just use self.

Comment: yes, just write `[self presentViewController:uploadVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: I don't get any error, the NSTimer stops, but it stays in the same pages.

Comment: @NiravKotecha I change the code, and it works. Thank youuuuuuuuuu!!!!